# How do I fetch all the folders in Salesforce using REST API

Tags: rest-api

I need to fetch list of all the folders in Documents section in Salesforce using REST API. Current API gets the information for a particular folder using folderId but I need to fetch all the folders in one go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a SOQL query on [Folder](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_folder.htm). Something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, AccessType FROM Folder where Type = 'Document'
```

Which would be a GET request to (change na5 to match your instance):

```
https://na5.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/query/?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Name%2C%20DeveloperName%2C%20AccessType%20FROM%20Folder%20where%20Type%20%3D%20%27Document%27
```

The JSON response will be something like:

```
{
    "totalSize": 15,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Folder",
                "url": "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Folder/00l700000000001AAA"
            },
            "Id": "00l70000000wp7KAAQ",
            "Name": "Test",
            "DeveloperName": "Test",
            "AccessType": "Public"
        }, //...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you guide me how to create new folder in Salesforce chatter? All I can see is adding new files not folder.

Comment: @Malik According to [Chatter REST API Developer's Guide - ](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_folders.htm) you can use `/chatter/folders/folderId/items`. Feel free to ask a new question for this (unless you can find the same question already)